# What's minimum required code to MODIFY a WebGL shader at runtime?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, shader

Suppose I have created a WebGL program, attached some initial shaders, linked the program, validated and after some time I want to modify source of one of the attached shaders.

Should I create a new WebGL program with the `gl.createProgram()`, or I can just reuse it and attach shaders?

I'm a bit confused about this because there are a few methods to call:

```
gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
gl.compileShader(shader);
gl.attachShader(program, shader);
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.validateProgram(program);
```

Which of these are required for just modifying one of the shaders in a program? I assume linking is required. Do I need to create new shader instance or I can reuse the instance and use `gl.shaderSource()` to pass in new source? Do I need to attach new/old shader to the program. Should I detach old shader from the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create a new shader or program object if you are happy replacing the content of the existing objects. If you are replacing the content of the existing objects then the minimal set is:

```
gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
gl.compileShader(shader);
// gl.attachShader(program, shader);
gl.linkProgram(program);
```

i.e. you don't need to attach the shader object to the program because it is already attached, but you need to do everything else.

> Do I need to create new shader instance or I can reuse the instance and use gl.shaderSource() to pass in new source?

Either would work.

> Do I need to attach new/old shader to the program.

If you create a new shader object then yes, it will obviously need to be attached to the program object or it won't be usable in a program.

> Should I detach old shader from the program?

Yes; you'll get an `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error if you try to attach a shader if one is already attached at that shader type location.

Some general notes:

- A reused program object will continue to reflect the old shader behavior until you call `linkProgram`.
- The locations for uniform and attribute bindings may change in the new program, even if they have the same names. Either use static bindings or requery after link.

Comment: `validateProgram` is not required and you have to detach an existing shader before you attach a new one else you'll get an error

Comment: True - tweaked answer. I never quite understood why WebGL bothered with `validateProgram`, given it doesn't even return a boolean it's no more convenient than just querying the link state property. I.e. under what conditions is a shader linked successfully but not valid according to WebGL?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create new shaders. You do need to call `gl.shaderSource` to upload the new GLSL and then `gl.compileShader` and `gl.linkShader`.

This is a complicated part of the spec though. What are you trying to do?

If the link fails your program the program is no longer useable. If the link succeeds then you effectively have a new program and need to look up all new attribute and uniform locations.

You can create new shaders if you want and attach them to an existing program. Before you attach the new shaders you need to detach the old ones with `gl.detachShader(prg, oldShader)`

not sure this is helpful but you can think of internal `WebGLProgram` state like this

```
class WebGLProgram {
   Shader vertexShader;
   Shader fragmentShader;

   // status from last time you called gl.linkProgram
   int linkStatus;

   // message from last time you called gl.linkProgram  
   string infoLog;

   // internal program created by last SUCCESSFUL linkProgram
   Program validProgram; 
}

class Program {
  map<string, int> attribLocations;
  map<string, WebGLUniformLocation> uniformLocations;
  GPUProgramCode compiledProgram
}

class Shader {
  string src;

  // status from last time you called gl.compileShader
  int compileStatus;

  // message from last time you called gl.compileShader  
  string infoLog;

  // internal shader created from last successful compile
  GPUShaderCode compiledShader;
}
```

The only thing that matters when rendering is that `validProgram` on the `WebGLProgram` has a valid program. So for example

```
const prg = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(prg, validCompiledVertexShader);
gl.attachShader(prg, validCompiledFragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(prg);   

// our imaginary prg.validProgram now has a valid program

gl.detachShader(prg, validCompiledVertexShader);
gl.detachShader(prg, validCompiledFragmentShader);
gl.deleteShader(validCompiledVertexShader);
gl.deleteShader(validCompiledFragmentShader);
```

Is a perfectly valid way to use shaders. They only need to stick around long enough to call `linkProgram`.

Comment: The question seems to be how to *modify* a shader, how could you detach a shader that you're modifying?

Comment: Why would you detach a shader that your modifying? Whether it succeeds or fails is irrelevant until you link. To link you'd have to attach the shader. The spec says no errors are required until you link. In other words compling is allowed to return no errors. So given all that there is zero reason to detach to modify. So it comes down to why you want to modify. If you want to make a [glslsandbox.com](http://glslsandbox.com) like site you probably actually want to use a different program so if things fail the old one still works.